# jquery: Nested tabs click on document load

Tags: jquery

I have a kind of nested tabs structure where parent tab has id "parent_id" and child has id "child_id"

Initially both are closed which are to opened on document ready click.On document ready I need to open them both.

Code which i wrote for this was:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#parent_id").click();
    $("a#parent_id").click(function(){$("a#child_id").click();});
});
```

Here parent tab was opening but child was not, I need to open both(parent and child on document ready) Any reasons for this?

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Two points on performance though; the selector "a#parent" is much slower than just "#parent" by itself (the first looks up all links, then looks for the one with an ID of parent, the second just looks up the element with an ID of "parent").  Second, don't look it up twice, just do it once, assign to var, then call click again (or better, just chain the calls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are triggering the `event` for the parent before you assign a function to it.
Do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#parent_id").click(function(){$("a#child_id").click();});
    $("a#parent_id").click();
});
```